# HTML files not cached when requested on localhost

Tags: angularjs, caching, browser-cache

recently we made changes to one of our applications and we noticed that our customers are not getting the new views. So we decided to version the files so we can force the client's browsers to fetch the new views every time we have a new version.

So far so good, but we needed to test this in a local environment before deploying this change (the versioning). Unfortunately, on localhost the views are never cached. I noticed that the requests for the views are sent with Cache-Control:max-age=0. If I am not mistaking this causes the resource to not be cached.

I read also that this could be caused by the ETag header, so I removed it but the views are still not cached. Also, I set the Cache-Control:max-age=86400,public header in the response. So the only reason left was the Cache-Control:max-age=0 header in the request. So I tried to change the header. I set the cache-control header in the request to be Cache-Control:max-age=86400,public, but still no luck.

The views are requested by AngualarJS, they are templates in directives. There is also a difference in the IIS version that we are using locally and that on the server. Locally we are using 7.5 and on the server, it is 8.0. Could this be the problem?

Can anyone guide me to the right direction?

**Edit:**

The Disable Cache option in the chrome dev tools is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can think about is that you have the Disable Cache enabled in your browser, if it's just your local system:

[image]

Normally, getting around Browser caching is quite tricky, so most people have trouble *disabling* browser caching using headers. The `Cache-Control:max-age` unfortunately is not uniformly implemented across browsers. If the issue is still occurring inspite of the above, could you provide screenshots from the network tab on your Chrome developer tools?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I actually disabled this option first. :)

[Screenshot](http://image.prntscr.com/image/b549775f57864d42942d02fb7fb60e0a.png)